# Testing Saga Generator Functions using Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, redux-saga

I was trying to write unit tests for this generator function `logOffSaga` using Jest. I tried several ways but could not find a proper way to handle this promise. Can anyone help me to sort this out?

```
export function abcFunction() {
  return api(EndPoints.CONTROLS)
    .post('logoff')
    .then(response => ({ response }))
    .catch(error => ({ error }));
}

export function* logOffSaga() {
  yield take(LOGOFF);
  const { response, error } = yield abcFunction();

  if (response && response.status === ResponseCodes.OK) {
    yield something();
  } else if (error) {
    yield somethingElse();
  }
}
```

Unit test:

```
  const genlogOffSaga = logOffSaga();

  it('should wait for LOGOFF', () => {
    expect(genlogOffSaga.next().value).toEqual(take(LOGOFF));
  });
```

How can I test the rest of the code, based on the return value of `abcFunction`?

Comment: Using spies from Jasmine for example you could create a spy object on the api.post() method, and return an Promise that is resolved immediatly. More info: https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Spy.html

Comment: thanks but i want to do it using jest.

Comment: Sorry my bad! Jest has a same sort of functionality, they call it mocking: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-implementations

Comment: There is section on the docs about it. See https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing.html

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Thanks mate, but they are using tape. I want it from Jest.

Comment: @JoeriShoeby yes I saw that, but when it comes to generator functions and with this iterating, I have no idea how to mock and where to mock it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show the LOGOFF action.
It would be more clear to test that. Is LOGOFF an action that you are yielding ?

Comment: import { LOGOFF } from './Types';

export function Logoff() {
  return { type: LOGOFF, payload: null };
}

Comment: const action = 'LOGOFF';

it('should wait for LOGOFF', () => {
    expect(genlogOffSaga.next(action).value).toEqual(take(LOGOFF));
  });